# Firefox Compatibility

Tags: firefox, wiki

I am currently working on an year old project(website) which used to support Firefix 3.x.
But firefox is rapidly developing & releasing new versions. Some of the features are not working on newer versions now. Bugs are logged but which version is stable from FF ? Last time i saw 5 was there now 6 is also released.And 7 & 8 are also going to be rolled out to be soon .My question is which browser to support ? Have you started supporting for new firefox versions ?

Comment: What features are not working?

Answer (score 0):

The stable and supported Firefox versions right now are 6 and 3.6.

A week from tomorroW, it will be 7 and 3.6.

3.6 support will most likely be dropped in the not too distant future, at which point there will be only one supported version of Firefox.

That all said, what issues are you running into with the newer Firefox versions?  Links to the bugs that are logged?